# How to tell if SQL Server is local or remote?

Tags: sql-server

In my app the users gets to pick from a list of SQL Server in the network. The thing is I need to know if the chosen instance is a local or remote computer.

Is there a way I can ask that SQL instance what computer is she on? Is there a way a can figure that out?

**Edit1:** I want to know the host name where the SQL Server is hosted so I can then compare that to [`System.Environment.MachineName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename.aspx) and know for sure is that Sql Server is running on the same machine where my app is running

**Edit2:** `@@servername` returned my computername\sqlinstance while `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')` returns just the computername, which is exactly what I want

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [@@Servername](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187944.aspx), for example:

```
SELECT @@servername
```

Alternately you could do this

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')
```

From MSDN on the differences between these approaches:

> The ServerName property of the
>   SERVERPROPERTY function and
>   @@SERVERNAME return similar
>   information. The ServerName property
>   provides the Windows server and
>   instance name that together make up
>   the unique server instance.
>   @@SERVERNAME provides the currently
>   configured local server name.
>
> The ServerName property and
>   @@SERVERNAME return the same
>   information if the default server name
>   at the time of installation has not
>   been changed.
>
> If the local server name has been
>   changed from the default server name
>   at installation time, @@SERVERNAME
>   returns the new name.

Comment: I could not understand - how do you figure out from returned name whether it is local or remote?

Comment: @vgv8 - You compare it to the name of the local machine.

Comment: actually SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') is more accurate to what i need, edited my question

Comment: Moreover, it seems that @@servername can store OLD machine name, while SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') returns the current one, after rename. +1 for the answer

Answer (score 3):

Do you actually have login permissions on all the instance(s) of SQL Server? If so you could execute *sp_helpserver* or *@@servername* and compare the name returned with *Environment.MachineName*.

If you don't have login access, you can write a small C# console program to return the server name of every SQL Server instance on the local network:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Sql;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Retrieve the enumerator instance and then the data.
        SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance =
        SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
        System.Data.DataTable table = instance.GetDataSources();

        // Display the contents of the table.
        // The first column is the server name.
        DisplayData(table);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void DisplayData(System.Data.DataTable table)
    {
        foreach ( System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows )
        {
            foreach ( System.Data.DataColumn col in table.Columns )
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", col.ColumnName, row[col]);
            }
        Console.WriteLine("============================");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

sp_who2 returns the hostname

Comment: That would be the name associated with the logged in user(s), not the SQL instance.

Comment: Apologies - I guess I misunderstood the question, that second paragraph is misleading "Is there a way I can ask that SQL instance what computer he on?" where He = user.